# radeon rx580 won't set resolution to 4k

Tags: radeon, 4k-monitor

I have a 4k monitor (Samsung UE570). I had a GeForce GTX 1060 6Gb card in the system and it worked fine. I've swapped out to a Radeon RX580 and installed the driver (amdgpu), but now I can't set the resolution anything higher than 1280X1024.Ubuntu 16.04. Any suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I just had a similar problem.  I was ultimately able to get it to work at 30Hz with a second, lower resolution monitor attached, and then at the full 60Hz when I switched the HDMI cables.  Hopefully this helps the next person to run into this.